# Why is my drive read-only?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, manjaro, fstab

I recently installed Manjaro on my computer. I use two drives, an nvme for the OS and a SATA SSD for everything else. I mounted my drive through FSTAB but it mounts itself as read only.

LSBLK output:

```
sda           8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0 465,8G  0 part /mnt/games
nvme0n1     259:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 232,6G  0 part /
```

FSTAB:

```
UUID=0111-7DB7                            /boot/efi      vfat    umask=0077 0 2
UUID=c4ab30a4-6528-41f6-8949-97b90e4f7fc9 /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
UUID=ec64b5a7-9af9-4bb9-8648-4eb09348b848       /mnt/games      ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Comment: More information is needed. Add the contents of `/etc/fstab` and the output of `mount` to the question.

Comment: ext4 could remount itself RO when it detects fatal errors.